# how to use next-auth with upstash redis?

Tags: next.js, redis

In my code im using like this

```
function getGoogleCredentials() {
    const clientId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    const clientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

    if (!clientId || clientId.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Missing GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID')
    }

    if (!clientSecret || clientSecret.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Missing GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET')
    }

    return { clientId, clientSecret }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: UpstashRedisAdapter(db),
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },

    pages: {
        signIn: '/signin',
    },
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: getGoogleCredentials().clientId,
            clientSecret: getGoogleCredentials().clientSecret,
        }),
    ],
}
```

but it store in form of string and if i have to fetch all registered users then how i can fetch it ??